# Json/weird column transformation

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting some data incoming from a mongo database. Such table contains several columns and some os such columns are composed of a very strange format.

Example of one line of the column/series

```
'[{idEvento.$oid=63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677690003377, codigoTipoEvento=1, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677691800676, codigoTipoEvento=3, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6405cc8711c78c20369b4033, dataHoraEvento.$date=1678090851560, codigoTipoEvento=8, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985307560, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985309584, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}]'
```

This does not, at least for my shot knowledge, is a Json. I am struggling how to transform each "event" (composed of a {} item) into a list.

And after that, how could I query/filter data based on the containing of each event? Should I pd.explode the events into new lines and query as strings?

Comment: Please update your post to show the code you have tried and your expected output.

Comment: Looks like you need to write a small parser. What is the exact expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to "convert" the string to proper Json (using `re`) and then use standard `json.loads` ([Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MwZQOB/1)):

```py
import re
import json
import pandas as pd


s = "[{idEvento.$oid=63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677690003377, codigoTipoEvento=1, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677691800676, codigoTipoEvento=3, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6405cc8711c78c20369b4033, dataHoraEvento.$date=1678090851560, codigoTipoEvento=8, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985307560, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985309584, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}]"

s = re.sub(r"([^ =,\[\]\{\}]+)=([^ =,\[\]\{\}]+)", r'"\g<1>":"\g<2>"', s)
data = json.loads(s)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              idEvento.$oid dataHoraEvento.$date codigoTipoEvento mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao                                           _class
0  63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad        1677690003377                1                         032023                                              NaN
1  63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae        1677691800676                3                         032023                                              NaN
2  6405cc8711c78c20369b4033        1678090851560                8                         032023                                              NaN
3  6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831        1679985307560                6                         032023  br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil
4  6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832        1679985309584                6                         032023  br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil
```

---

NOTE: This works for this example, but the pattern might need to be adjusted for real case.

---

EDIT: To apply to a dataframe:

Consider following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [
            "[{idEvento.$oid=01_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677690003377, codigoTipoEvento=1, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677691800676, codigoTipoEvento=3, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6405cc8711c78c20369b4033, dataHoraEvento.$date=1678090851560, codigoTipoEvento=8, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985307560, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985309584, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}]",
            "[{idEvento.$oid=02_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677690003377, codigoTipoEvento=1, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677691800676, codigoTipoEvento=3, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6405cc8711c78c20369b4033, dataHoraEvento.$date=1678090851560, codigoTipoEvento=8, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985307560, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985309584, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}]",
            "[{idEvento.$oid=03_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677690003377, codigoTipoEvento=1, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677691800676, codigoTipoEvento=3, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6405cc8711c78c20369b4033, dataHoraEvento.$date=1678090851560, codigoTipoEvento=8, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985307560, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985309584, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}]",
        ]
    }
)

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               col1
0  [{idEvento.$oid=01_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677690003377, codigoTipoEvento=1, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677691800676, codigoTipoEvento=3, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6405cc8711c78c20369b4033, dataHoraEvento.$date=1678090851560, codigoTipoEvento=8, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985307560, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985309584, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}]
1  [{idEvento.$oid=02_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677690003377, codigoTipoEvento=1, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677691800676, codigoTipoEvento=3, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6405cc8711c78c20369b4033, dataHoraEvento.$date=1678090851560, codigoTipoEvento=8, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985307560, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985309584, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}]
2  [{idEvento.$oid=03_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677690003377, codigoTipoEvento=1, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae, dataHoraEvento.$date=1677691800676, codigoTipoEvento=3, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6405cc8711c78c20369b4033, dataHoraEvento.$date=1678090851560, codigoTipoEvento=8, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985307560, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}, {idEvento.$oid=6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832, dataHoraEvento.$date=1679985309584, codigoTipoEvento=6, mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao=032023, _class=br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil}]
```

Then:

```py
def fn(x):
    x = re.sub(r"([^ =,\[\]\{\}]+)=([^ =,\[\]\{\}]+)", r'"\g<1>":"\g<2>"', x)
    return json.loads(x)

out = df["col1"].apply(fn).explode().apply(pd.Series)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                 idEvento.$oid dataHoraEvento.$date codigoTipoEvento mesAnoReferenciaContabilizacao                                           _class
0  01_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad        1677690003377                1                         032023                                              NaN
0     63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae        1677691800676                3                         032023                                              NaN
0     6405cc8711c78c20369b4033        1678090851560                8                         032023                                              NaN
0     6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831        1679985307560                6                         032023  br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil
0     6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832        1679985309584                6                         032023  br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil
1  02_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad        1677690003377                1                         032023                                              NaN
1     63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae        1677691800676                3                         032023                                              NaN
1     6405cc8711c78c20369b4033        1678090851560                8                         032023                                              NaN
1     6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831        1679985307560                6                         032023  br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil
1     6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832        1679985309584                6                         032023  br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil
2  03_63ffaec3cdc01e6352729bad        1677690003377                1                         032023                                              NaN
2     63ffb5c8cdc01e6352729bae        1677691800676                3                         032023                                              NaN
2     6405cc8711c78c20369b4033        1678090851560                8                         032023                                              NaN
2     6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f831        1679985307560                6                         032023  br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil
2     6422b4c97e45dd75abb4f832        1679985309584                6                         032023  br.com.bb.rcp.model.vantagens.HistoricoContabil
```

Comment: How could I encapsule all this to run over a pandas series (column of the data frame)?